# How can I get access to items of a modal dialog in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I just want to get access to an object in the modal dialog. The following example will explain exactly what I'm trying to do:

(This code is not working)

```
    CAddDlg dlg;
CString S;
dlg.DoModal();
dlg.GetDlgItem(IDC_NAME)->GetWindowTextW(S);
MessageBox(S);
```

But an assert will fail and I can't get the text of the Edit control.
What should I do?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945537/getting-edit-box-text-from-a-modal-mfc-dialog-after-it-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the controls of modal dialogs from outside. Even if you could, it's not a good idea. The caller of the dialog should not know how the data is represented in the dialog. What is now an edit control could be a listbox in the future.

The way to go is declare getter functions which you call after `DoModal()` (if it returned IDOK) and get the values there.

Check [Can I return a custom value from a dialog box's DoModal function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111809/can-i-return-a-custom-value-from-a-dialog-boxs-domodal-function) for some examples